# print javascript only to front end

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress app that I will always have full control over. I want to make sure that I have control over the jquery version. So I have a plugin that re-registers jquery:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-core');
wp_register_script('jquery', URL_CONSTANT . "/application/includes/jquery-ui-1.8.13/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js");
wp_register_script('jquery-ui-core', URL_CONSTANT . "/application/includes/jquery-ui-1.8.13/js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js", array('jquery'));
```

Now everybody's gonna see what just happened when I went into the dashboard, lol. I'm getting a jQuery not defined error and nothing will work.

Has anybody got any ideas of how I should tackle this problem. One suggestion I have is to replace the jquery file in the wp-includes folder (or where ever it is), but I don't want to have to do this for every update I do to wordpress.

any suggestions appreciated,
daithi

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are talking about - but you can namespace your plugin and then you don't have to worry about overriding the jQuery version included in Wordpress. What does 'I always have full control over' mean? What is app? A plugin?

Comment: when I say 'I always have full control over' I mean if I want to change the jquery version i can.
And yes an app is a plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bundle your own jquery version with your app so that you don't need to worry about the version shipped with wordpress. Taking over the wordpress jquery version would be a *very bad thing* to do.

This guy talks about the proper way to use jQuery with plugins. Read all the way to the end. #5 is the most relevant to you.

http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/

Comment: You should also look into namespacing your plugin so that you don't create conflicts. If you use a common function name like 'getPost' then you could conflict either with core wordpress or other plugins. Google it up!

Comment: ah of course. Feel bit stupid. Should have only deregistered if !admin. Explanaition is #2 in the link given by @mrtsherman, cheers for your help ;)